# Dialog Continuation Issue on Bot Framework V4

Tags: botframework

I want to start a user dialog right after a welcome message has been displayed in my bot - without any initial user interaction. 
Code snippet to accomplish that:

```
public RootDialogBot(BotServices services, BotAccessors accessors, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (loggerFactory == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
            }

            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RootDialogBot>();            
            _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
            _botServices = services ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

            _studentProfileAccessor = _accessors.UserState.CreateProperty<StudentProfile>("studentProfile");

            if (!_botServices.QnAServices.ContainsKey("QnAMaker"))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException($"Invalid configuration. Please check your '.bot' file for a QnA service named QnAMaker'.");
            }
            if (!_botServices.LuisServices.ContainsKey("LUIS"))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException($"Invalid configuration. Please check your '.bot' file for a Luis service named LUIS'.");
            }                     
                .Add(new Activity2MainDialog(_accessors.UserState, Activity2MainDialog))
                .Add(new Activity2LedFailToWorkDialog(_accessors.UserState, Activity2LedFailToWorkDialog));            
        }
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
...
if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {                
                if (turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded != null)
                {
                    // Save the new turn count into the conversation state.
                    await _accessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                    await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                    var message = "Welcome!";
                    await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, dc, message,cancellationToken);  //Welcome message
                }
            } 
...
}
private static async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, DialogContext dc,string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(Activity2MainDialog, "activity2MainDialog", cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
```

The dialog (Activity2MainDialog) works fine until it reaches a `return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);` call. 
Then it halts.
I believe it has something to do with the conversation state but I still couldn't find a solution for that.
Code snippet of the `return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);` call

```
public class Activity2MainDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private static BellaMain BellaMain = new BellaMain();
        private static FTDMain FTDMain = new FTDMain();
        private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<StudentProfile> _studentProfileAccessor;        
    ...
        public Activity2MainDialog(UserState userState, string dialogMainId)
                : base(dialogMainId)
        {
            InitialDialogId = Id;
            _studentProfileAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<StudentProfile>("studentProfile");

            WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                MsgWelcomeStepAsync
        ...                
            };

            // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(dialogMainId, waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MsgWelcomeStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("**Oi**", "Oi", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> QuestGoAheadStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            message = "Vamos nessa?";
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message , message , cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            retryPromptMessage = message;
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt),
                        new PromptOptions
                        {
                            Prompt = null,
                            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text(retryPromptMessage, retryPromptSpeakMessage), InputHints.ExpectingInput),            
                            Choices = new[]
                            {
                                    new Choice {Value = "Sim", Synonyms = new List<string> {"yes","yeah","esta","ta","esta","ok","vamos","curti","curtir","claro","tá","sei","top"}},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Não", Synonyms = new List<string> {"no"}}
                            }.ToList(),
                            Style = ListStyle.Auto                            
                        });
        }
```

Thoughts on how to fix it? Thx

Comment: Please include a sample of the code that includes the `return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);` call. What happens when it "halts"? Is there an error? What does the user experience?

Comment: Thx. It simply halts. No error message is displayed.
When the code is ran the bot emulator we can see messages rolling out but nothing is shown on the message window.
However, when the program is stopped they are displayed at once.
Please have a look at the screen shot.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httIorea3zL9qWk954hQ?e=wsrzvV
Aditional Code on the return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken) is now added in the issue statement.
You may get a more comphrehensive code at https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnpERZZbH7httIosV2-i6yWeng9bSg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the issue is the `ContinueDialog` call. You need to end that step with:

```cs
return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
```

See [CoreBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L49) for more example code.

If this *doesn't* fix your issue, let me know and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: You are right. It's working now! Thx a lot for the help.